# How to pass slashes in Elasticsearch query using PHP?

Tags: php, elasticsearch

Below mentioned elastic search query which is working fine if we hit it directly,

```
{
 "query": {
    "query_string": {
        "query": "\"testtext/123\""
    }
 }
}
```

In PHP array how to pass the above-mentioned query with backslashes. I tried the below code which gives an error response.

```
$query = array(
  "query"=>[
    "query_string"=> [
      "query"=>"\".$string."\"
    ]
  ]
);
```

Error is:

> syntax error, unexpected '' (T_NS_SEPARATOR)

Comment: What error exactly? Have you checked the content of $string is exactly what you expect, same as the hard-coded example? Have you checked the array gets encoded to the same JSON format?

Comment: @ADyson syntax error, unexpected '\' (T_NS_SEPARATOR) error im getting.

Comment: Ah if course. `\ ` is an escape character so it escapes the second `"`, so it thinks the strings are not ended. Replace with `\\ `. Always easier when you know the error message

Comment: @ADyson can you add an example. I will check

Comment: Why don’t you just use _single_ quotes for the string delimiters in the first place.

Comment: P.s. to avoid downvotes in future always give the full information about the problem including error messages

Comment: @ADyson I think what they actually want to create here, is JSON. So IMHO this should be just `"query"=>'"'.$string.'"'` in the code that creates the PHP data object, and `json_encode` will take care of escaping the double quotes in the output.

Comment: @CBroe just figured that out myself :-) - see updated answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\`  is an escape character, you need to escape that itself otherwise it escapes the second `"` so PHP thinks the strings are unfinished. You need to resolve the syntax error and also ensure the the second quote mark is actually part of the string, not a PHP delimiter.

The simplest way actually would be to use single quotes for the string delimiter in PHP:

```
$query = array(
  "query"=>[
    "query_string"=> [
      "query"=>'"'.$string.'"'
    ]
  ]
);
```

Comment: above mentioned query I tried, it gives response but not a matched result, it gives all  output results

Comment: Ah I think it's because the inner quote mark is supposed to actually be part of the search string. Hang on I will figure it out

Comment: I tried this query with slashes to get matched results. If that one not works no use above fix.